# Webgl: Stride not working. Doesn't stride past values in buffer

Tags: javascript, webgl, stride

I'm doing a lorenz-attractor in webgl and am playing around with multi-dimensional strange attractors in general. I made a particle system for this based in webgl which works fine, for the most part. The particle system works by rendering the x and y values of a gl.POINTS while keeping higher dimensions in the same buffer for calculations of their respective derivative. Buffer example: x=buffer[i], y=buffer[i+1], z=buffer[i+2], w=buffer[i+3] and so forth.

I've noticed that the points disappear when z is above 1. This is another issue I can't solve at the moment, so I bypass it by simply striding over the values entirely since z shouldn't be a part of the visualization anyway, but this stride system doesn't work.

I know an alternative solution would be to make a copy of the positions array containing only x and y values and pass that into the shader program as a 2 dimensional system, and this works! Doing so removes the "disappearing points" problem, but it causes some lag at high amounts of particles due to garbage collection which I'd like to be without.

This is the buffer code:

```
dims = 3;
drawScene(gl, program, positions) {
        gl.clearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
        gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        var positionAttributeLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "a_position");        
        var positionBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBuffer);

        // positions is array of x,y,z coordinates 
        gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(positions), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
        gl.enableVertexAttribArray(positionAttributeLocation);

        const size = this.dims;         
        const type = gl.FLOAT;
        const normalize = true; 
        const stride = 4 * (this.dims-2); // gl.FLOAT=4 bytes, then stride +1 extra per dim above 2
        const offset = 0;
        gl.vertexAttribPointer(
            positionAttributeLocation, size, type, normalize, stride, offset);

        const primitiveType = gl.POINTS;
        const count = positions.length / this.dims;

        gl.drawArrays(primitiveType, offset, count);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stride is wrong. Stride should just be `dims * 4` and if you only want x and y then size is just 2.

Other issues

1. Plus you can't normalize floats
2. You should look up locations at init time not render time
3. You should create one buffer and reuse it

   The code is currently creating a new buffer every frame and will eventually run out of memory
4. The code is doing a conversion from a native JavaScript array to a new Float32Array every frame. That's also an allocation.

   You should just create one Float32Array and update the values in it
5. The code is potentially allocating a new array inside WebGL each frame by calling `gl.bufferData`. Instead call `gl.bufferSubData` to just upload the data
6. If you're changing data in a buffer often you should mark it as `gl.DYNAMIC_DRAW` to let WebGL know you plan to update it often. It can use that as a perf hint.

```js
const gl = document.querySelector('canvas').getContext('webgl');

const vs = `
attribute vec2 a_position;
void main() {
  gl_Position = vec4(a_position, 0, 1);
  gl_PointSize = 5.0;
}`;

const fs = `
precision mediump float;
void main() {
  gl_FragColor = vec4(1, 0, 0, 1);
}`;

const prg = twgl.createProgram(gl, [vs, fs]);
const positionAttributeLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(prg, 'a_position');

const dims = 3;
const num = 100;
const positions = new Float32Array(dims * num);

// create the buffer at init time
const positionBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBuffer);
// just allocate space
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positions.byteLength, gl.DYNAMIC_DRAW);

function drawScene(gl, program, positions) {
  gl.clearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
  gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

  // update positions
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBuffer);
  gl.bufferSubData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, positions);
  
  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(positionAttributeLocation);

  const size = 2;
  const type = gl.FLOAT;
  const normalize = false;
  const stride = 4 * dims;
  const offset = 0;
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(
    positionAttributeLocation, size, type, normalize, stride, offset);
    
  gl.useProgram(program);

  const primitiveType = gl.POINTS;
  const count = positions.length / dims;

  gl.drawArrays(primitiveType, offset, count);
}

function render(time) {
  time *= 0.001;
  
  for (let i = 0; i < num * dims; i += dims) {
    const u = i / dims / num;
    const a = u * Math.PI * 2 + time;
    positions[i    ] = Math.sin(a);
    positions[i + 1] = Math.cos(a * 1.1);
    positions[i + 2] = Math.cos(a * 1.2) * 1.2;
  }
  drawScene(gl, prg, positions);
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}
requestAnimationFrame(render);
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/4.x/twgl.min.js"></script>
<canvas></canvas>
```

Also it's more common to use a [projection matrix](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-3d-orthographic.html) and a [view matrix](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-3d-camera.html) to change the space represented by the canvas. Then instead of not using Z you could just choose a different space to be represented in the canvas, one that contains your Z range.